# Symfony2: Add form templates in bundle dependency injection

Tags: forms, symfony, templates, dependency-injection

The [official documentation on how to create a custom field](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-a-template-for-the-field) recommends putting the following lines in the application configuration (`app/config/config.yml`) to register additional templates:

```
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - 'AcmeDemoBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
```

Is there another way to add the template to the twig form resources by loading it in the dependency injection code for the bundle? Any code examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the [TwigExtension](https://github.com/symfony/TwigBundle/blob/00928603477bc1c69e9df0679dab33a35a73e755/DependencyInjection/TwigExtension.php) (inside the TwigBundle), you'll see that the configuration is stored in a `twig.form.resources` parameter:

```
$container->setParameter('twig.form.resources', $config['form']['resources']);
```

Your bundle can add elements to this parameter inside a Compiler pass. A compiler pass is executed after all bundle extensions are loaded and the container has a complete set of services. Learn more on how to create compiler passes in the [Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/compilation.html#creating-a-compiler-pass).

Basically, want you want to do is something like:

```
$resources = [];
if ($container->hasParameter('twig.form.resources')) {
    $resources = $container->getParameter('twig.form.resources');
}

$resources[] = 'your_awesome_template_resource.twig';

$container->setParameter('twig.form.resources', $resources);
```

Answer (score -1):

I want to do the same thing, I want to load form template from bundle without adding anything to the config.yml. Here is how it's done:

You need to implement `PrependExtensionInterface` in your extensions, which is located in the your `bundle folder/DependencyInjection/BundleNameExtension.php`

like so:

```
class YourExtension extends Extension implements PrependExtensionInterface {
    ...
    public function prepend(ContainerBuilder $container) {
        foreach (array_keys($container->getExtensions()) as $name) {
            switch ($name) {
                case 'twig':
                    $container->prependExtensionConfig(
                        $name,
                        array('form' => array('resources' => array('YourExtension:Form:fields.html.twig')))
                    );
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is full example taken from SummerNote bundle:
https://github.com/solilokiam/SummernoteBundle/blob/a510386c49144ff0f4391c460bcc1640fd26b691/DependencyInjection/SolilokiamSummernoteExtension.php